# Linear Programming library for C++ on Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, library, c++, api

I am currently facing a linear programming problem that I would like to solve in C++. There are equality and non-equality constraints, i.e. max a^{T} x subject to Bx >= c and Dx = e.

What actively maintained libraries exist with a good C++ interface? What would you recommend?

Many thanks!

Platform: Linux (Debian)
Programming language: C++ for interface
License: "gratis" (i.e. doesn't have to be open-source type of "free")

Answer (score 0):

The Minizinc IDE is free and contains a few free solvers, and optional third-party solvers. On [the Minizinc "software" page](https://www.minizinc.org/software.html) it is documented how the libraries are implemented and what they are good for.

Comment: Many thanks for the recommendation! I was rather looking for something that could be used in a pre-existing code, i.e. an interface that could be called from the current code, I apologize for not having made that clearer! I ended up using lp_solve, which is a bit old but performs very well.

Comment: @fermion Can you add an answer for lp_solve, detailing how it solved the question?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, sure. `lpsolve` is well tested, runs on linux, has a C++ interface, and is free to use. It has all the features that I originally asked for (i.e. equality and non-equality constraints). The part about being actively maintained is a bit less of a given here, but it's close enough. I hope that was helpful.